# Showing quantity in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have the price show in JavaScript when my button is clicked but it is just showing me my alert. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong? This is my function:

```
function prompttotalCost() {
    var totalCost;
    var costPerCD;
    var numCDs;
    numCDS = prompt("Enter the number of Melanie's CDs you want to buy");
    if (numCDS > 0) {
        totalCost = totalCost + (costPerCD * numCDs);
        alert("totalCost+(costPerCD*numCDs)");
        totalCost = 0;
        costPerCD = 5;
        numCDs = 0;
    } else {
        alert("0 is NOT a valid purchase quantity. Please press 'OK' and try again");
    } // end if
} // end function prompttotalCost
```

Comment: Keep an eye on the area below the edit box. It gives a realtime preview of your post.

Comment: Variables need to be outside string literals, remove the `"` in your alert

Comment: Get rid of the quotation marks in your `alert` with the variables and see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `numCDs` is a string, not a number, because `prompt` returns a string. You can e.g. use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert it to a number:

```
numCDS = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of Melanie's CDs you want to buy"));
```

Next thing: You are not assigning a value to `totalCost` before using it – that's bad. Either change `var totalCost;` to `var totalCost = 0;` or change `totalCost = totalCost + (costPerCD * numCDs);` to `totalCost = (costPerCD * numCDs);`.

Also, in your `alert` invocation, you are putting something that you want to be executed as code into a string. Change

```
alert("totalCost+(costPerCD*numCDs)");
```

to something like this:

```
alert("totalCost is "+totalCost);
```